# Escaping for insert to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I have a php page that uses `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape content that contains single quotes. I believe it is using utf-8 (but I am not sure). When I insert some content, I get the following mysql warning (and it adds a ? instead of ' in the content):

Incorrect string value: '\x92t ...

Here is an example of my php:

```
    $link = ConnectToServer($theIntranet, $theUser, $thePW);
$theTagToFind = 'ac';
$theTagToUse = 'trc';
$database = '{databaseName}';
$theQuery = "SELECT * FROM {$database}.templates
            WHERE content like '%{" . $theTagToFind . ":%'";
$updates = fopen('001_intranet_change' . strtoupper($theTagToFind) . 'to' . strtoupper($theTagToUse) . '.sql', 'w+');
$rollback = fopen('001_intranet_change' . strtoupper($theTagToUse) . 'backto' . strtoupper($theTagToFind) . '.sql', 'w+');
$theResultHandle = mysql_query($theQuery, $link);

$comment = "--Update All $theTagToFind tags to $theTagToUse tags in $database --";
fwrite($updates, $comment . "\r\n\r\n");
fwrite($rollback, "--Rollback - Convert all $theTagToUse tags back to $theTagToFind tags --\r\n\r\n");
mysql_set_charset('latin1');
while (($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($theResultHandle)) != false)
{
    $rb_content = $data['content'];
    $data['content'] = preg_replace("/{" . $theTagToFind . ":/", "{" . $theTagToUse . ":", $data['content']);
    $theResult[] = $data;
    $update_script = "\r\n 
    Update $database.templates
    SET content = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($data['content']) . "'
    WHERE _id = " .$data['_id'] . ";";

    $rollback_script = "\r\n
    UPDATE $database.templates
    SET content = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($rb_content) . "'
    WHERE _id = " . $data['_id'] . ";";;
    fwrite($updates, $update_script);
    fwrite($rollback, $rollback_script);
}
fclose ($updates);
fclose($rollback);

print_r($theResult);
```

and `$data['content']` could equal something like:

"Hello, 
Please remember to contact the doctor's office at......"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

you have to be sure that charset in your table definition also set to utf8

Comment: I tried to use mysql_set_charset('latin1') because that is what the table is set as. Unfortunately, what I am doing is writing to a text file to import later (I have to create a way to update the production version of the table). I will post the rest of my code and you can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your server is configured correctly and [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are turned off? These can have the effect of double escaping values.

You can test this by looking at the `$_POST` data to see if it's been modified from what you'd expect. If so, see if you can fix the setting in `php.ini`.

As a note, you should not be using `mysql_query` in new code. It's dangerous, deprecated, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. Using [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is the safest and easiest way to do escaping.

In your short example here it looks like you've forgotten to escape `$data['_id']` which means it's a possible SQL injection bug. Even one mistake can have severe consequences, so never, ever put unescaped data into a query string.

Comment: Thanks tadman, (I didn't downvote). This is an intranet application, and the organization's standard is to use mysql_query() (I guess they don't plan on updating PHP any time soon). I am pretty sure this error has something to do with mysql and uft8, not double escaping (since the utf8 representation of a single quote is \x92)

Comment: Magic quotes cannot cause Incorrect string error; mysql_query is not dangerous; escaped _id will help noone.

Comment: Well, an unescaped value is not something you want going into your query, ever, intranet application or not. What does the value look like before escaping? You need to `echo` it to find out.

Comment: @tadman, I agree that values should be escaped. Since I am simply writing a utilitiy script to update data and move it from one db to another, it is not that important (no user input at all). That wasn't explained in my post, so there is no way you'd know that. However, there is something different happening that is preventing the escaping

Comment: "This is an intranet application, and the organization's standard is to use mysql_query()", this sounds like a dysfunctional organization.  In the past I've (passive aggressively) encapsulated calls to insecure methods inside wrapper functions called `VulnerableMySql_Query()` with a code comment like '//As per [requester's email address] using deprecated method:'.  Choices like this can seem like minor nits but when you are responsible for maintaining and fixing it helps knowing where external requirements are undermining your efforts.

Comment: I should clarify (or perhaps just shut up) that I'm not suggesting that you be difficult, just that you use code as a record of your decision making.  It will also make later refactoring a lot easier :)